# MSBuild ignores local project reference, but Visual Studio works fine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csc

I have a .Net/C# solution which contains two projects:

- Web Project (ASP.Net Web API)
- Unit-Test project (C#, etc)

The Unit Test project references the Web Project and using a Test Framework performs some unit tests against it.

In Visual Studio 2017, all of this builds perfectly run and the web api runs perfectly and so do my unit tests.

When I come to build is using MSBuild via the command line (either locally or on own build server), the Unit Test project reports...

> error CS0103: The name 'WebApi' does not exist in the current context [c:\Code\UnitTests.csproj]

...it can't find the WebApi project at all!

Both projects are configured as .Net V4.5.2 and 'Any CPU'.

I've tried various:

- Versions of MsBuild
- Versions of the C# Language (in case C# 6 was causing issues as msbuild doesn't always support C# V5)

I'm building them using

> c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe"  C:\Code\MyProject.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release

Additionally, the Unit Test project can reference other .Net Class Libaries and other ASP.NET Web API projects without problem, so it must be something to do with the ASP.NET Web API project rather than the Unit Test project itself.

I've noticed that when msbuild comes to compile the Unit Test project it shows the command line for the **csc.exe** compile part and it will include all references to other project, but never includes the Web API project, so msbuild must either:

- Think the Web Api reference is not required and ignores it, or
- Fails to detect it in the csproj file (but VS detects it perfectly fine)

Update: The Web API project was added to the solution 2-3 years ago (likely VS2013/5), but the Unit Test project was added this week using VS 2017, but I also tried VS2015 and same error.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I think better trying MSBuild from Visual Studio 2017 directory - _$VisualStudioInstallDir$/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe_. You gave the example of executable command that use MSBuild 14, while Visual Studio 2017 use MSBuild 15.

Comment: I believe that problem by reason of discrepancy ToolsVersion between MSBuild 14 (v14) and the project (v15).